# ImportError my_app.settings Django

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I searched all night yesterday for a solution, but I couldn't find one.
I am trying to deploy a Django project from my computer to the server.

In the server there are these folders:

> .
>  |--- apps_wsgi 
> |      |--
>   veredaeditora.wsgi
>  |--- awstats_data
>  |--- error.log
>  |---
>   www

Inside the www folder is my project, like the manage.py file.

I keep getting this error, don't know why.

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'veredaeditora.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named veredaeditora.settings
```

Below is the *veredaeditora.wsgi* file:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/veredaeditora/apps_wsgi')
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/veredaeditora/apps_wsgi/.python-eggs'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='veredaeditora.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And here is the *wsgi.py* file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "veredaEditora.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application<br>
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I did the startproject command, the project name was veredaEditora.
Can the capital E being causing the problem? And in my computer the django version is 1.7.3 and in the server is 1.6.

Just to inform, I don't know anything about apache or wsgi.

Any help would be great.

Comment: sys.path.append('/home/veredaeditora/www') should do it

Comment: It didn't work. I tried to create a new project, but I still get the erro.

Comment: Actually, did work. The problem was with the django-admin startproject veredaEditora. The capital E made the problems, cause in the server is veredaeditora. I had to create another project without the capital E to be able to fix the suggestion given by Alvaro.
Thank you for your help!